# How to enforce v2 bosh manifests?

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa, cf-bosh

I understand from experience and the [documentation](http://bosh.io/docs/cloud-config.html) that bosh directors (v257+) do not enforce v2 manifests by default. 
Moreover, I understand that a [team admin](http://bosh.io/docs/director-users-uaa-perms.html) cannot update the cloud-config. 
However, when using a v1 manifest, a team admin can write a deployment manifest that overrules the cloud config. The team admin simply gets a warning `Deprecation: Ignoring cloud config. Manifest contains 'networks' section.`

In a setup where bosh's team functionality is used, is it possible to configure the bosh director in a way that team admins are forced to use v2 manifests and cannot ignore the cloud-config?

Answer (score 1):

According to the information I got in the official slack channel, the short answer is: "no".